# 404 Not Found this is not redirecting based on applications_id

Tags: php, laravel

I have an update query in laravel but is not redirecting based on `applications_id` what could be the problem.

below is my controller code SoleProprietorController.php :

```
    public function create_user_applicationform2(Request $request, $applications_id)
    {
return redirect('soleproprietorship_applicationform3/'.$applications->applications_id);
}

    public function  soleproprietorship_applicationform3($applications_id)
    {

        $applications_id = \DB::table('applications')->where('applications_id', $applications_id)->get();

           return view('soleproprietorship_applicationform3')->with('applications_id', $applications_id);
    }
```

And my model Applications.php

```
class Applications extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
  protected $primaryKey = 'applications_id';
    /*
     * Important records to be filled
     */
    public $fillable = [
       'applications_id'
    ];

}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/soleproprietorship_applicationform3/{applications_id}', 'SoleProprietorController@soleproprietorship_applicationform3')->name('home');
```

Comment: share your controller and route please

Comment: @Manojkiran.A i have shared my route and contoller

Comment: here you have two methods which methos is not workomg fine

Comment: ```create_user_applicationform2``` is not redirecting to soleproprietorship_applicationform3 based on applications_id ```return redirect('soleproprietorship_applicationform3/'.$applications->applications_id);```when redirecting to soleproprietorship_applicationform3 it not picking the applications_id instead it is giving me 404 error that soleproprietorship_applicationform3 not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$application->applications_id` needs to be `$applications_id`

```
public function create_user_applicationform2(Request $request, $applications_id)
{
   return redirect('soleproprietorship_applicationform3/'. $applications_id);
}
```

Comment: @Manojkiran wait I try I will get back to you.